# Delete the third char from line using sed

Tags: regex, sed

The following sed syntax deletes the first `@` character if it exists in a string:

```
 sed 's/^@\(.*\)/\1/'
```

But how to change it to delete the `@` character only if it's in the **third** position? 
For example, I would need to delete it in the following line:

```
 AB@CDEF
```

I need the script to verify if the third character is `@`, and if so then to delete it from the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sed 's/^\(..\)@\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

Comment: Very good
many THX
yael

Comment: you do not need the rest of the line,  s/^\\(..\\)@/\1' is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize for any character at any given position *`n`*:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)./\1/'
```

which deletes the third character. Just change the number "2" to *`n-1`*.

You can use a variable like this:

```
n=2
echo "$line" | sed "s/^\(.\{${n}\}\)./\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% sed -e '/^..@/ { s,^\(..\)@,\1, }'
```

means:

- if line starts with 3 characters, the third is a '@'
- throw out the @, but keep the first chars